# Vibrations at idle

Tags: mazda

After installing a rebuilt transmission, it was slipping and sticking in 3rd gear. A 2nd rebuilt transm eliminated those problems but this one has caused major vibrations in gear, or neutral, or park at factory spec 750 rpm idle. When press accelerator to 1,000 rpm, the vibrations stop. Motor + trans mounts + idle air control valve have all been replaced w/ no effect. Mazda service advises they cannot boost the idle due to factory settings. It is even worse when the A/C is on as the idle drops below 750 unlike my Miata where the idle increases when the A/C is on.  Is there a way to change these settings, or place something on the accelerator like a govenor to prevent it from going below 1,000 rpm? I recognize that the torque converter may be defective, but I do not want to spend any more money on the transm and the vibrations are beyond annoying and embarrassing.

Comment: What model & variant of car is it?

Comment: I would also suggest that you don't get locked into one line of thinking. Idle roughness could also be caused by a missing cylinder which appears to go away with increased speed. If it were a torque converter, I'd expect the vibration to get worse as the RPMs go up.